# Trying to use a string variable with infile.open() is treated as a char in c++

Tags: c++, string, c++11, getline

I'm trying to make a program where the user enters a file name and then the program tries opening it and checks to see if it is open. I am using the getline function. Here is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;


void readGameFile();

int main()
{
    readGameFile();
    return 0;
}


void readGameFile()
{
    ifstream infile;
    string s;
    string fileName;
    getline(cin,fileName);
    infile.open(fileName);
    if(infile.is_open())
    {
        cout << "It worked!"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "You messed up"<<endl;  
    }
}
```

It gives me this error:
23:22: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_ifstream::open(std::string&)’

23:22: note: candidate is:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/fstream:531:7: note: void std::basic_ifstream<_CharT, _Traits>::open(const char*, std::ios_base::openmode) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits, std::ios_base::openmode = std::_Ios_Openmode]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/fstream:531:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string}’ to ‘const char*’

So, I'm not really sure what the problem is. I'm fairly new to programming, I'm trying to figure this out for a class project(this isn't the assignment, it's just a generic version of the problem I'm having in my project so far). If you can give any help, that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Your standard library implementation doesn't seem to be up to date. [It's valid C++11](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cfd52fcb97ae7579).

Comment: Most compilers will use C++11 if you add a `-std=c++11` command-line option. Note that `-std=c++14` might now be a better choice, though.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I am using g++ on linux, using vim as my editor. Would you know how I could check what version of c++ is being used by g++? And also how I can upgrade that? What I mean is, is there any way I can make it automatically compile with the proper standard, instead of using the old one? I'm using g++ 4.6, which I believe should be using c++11, right?

Answer (score 2):

There are two overloads for [`open`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/open):

```
void open( const char *filename, ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::in );
void open( const std::string &filename, ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::in );
```

The second one is only available since C++11. You are apparently either not compiling in C++11 mode or using an out of date compiler. There is another overload that takes `const char*`, so this should work regardless:

```
infile.open(fileName.c_str());
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do following way

```
ifstream aStream;    
 aStream.open(textFile.c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `infile.open(fileName);` with `infile.open(fileName.c_str());`

`open()` takes a parameter of type `const char*`. In your case, you are trying to pass a `string`. The above code should work for your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The answers already given are correct, but the entire answer is scattered between 2 answers and a comment. Here's a more complete answer.

The `open()` you have used is the overloaded version available since C++11, which takes an `std::string` parameter for the filename.

```
void open( const std::string &filename, ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::in );
```

However, your compiler seems to have the default behavior of compiling in a pre-C++11 standard, under which `open()` can only take a `const char*` parameter (ie, a C string).

```
void open( const char *filename, ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::in );
```

To fix your problem, you can do one of two things:

- If your compiler supports c++11 compilation, google how to do that. In g++, for example, you'd use `g++ -std=c++11 myprogram.cpp` (or better yet, the latest C++14 standard with `g++ -std=c++14 myprogram.cpp`)
- If you don't want to or can't compile that way, then change your `open()` to use a C string - `infile.open(fileName.c_str());`

Comment: I am using g++ and I tried compiling it that way, but unfortunately it said that the command can not be recognized, referring to -std=c++11. Would you happen to know how I can fix that by updating g++ or something similar? I'm using version 4.6 currently. Thanks!

Comment: In 4.6, I recall that you could use `-std=c++0x` instead. But you really should update. The process of doing that depends on which Linux distro you are using.